# Divergence of $\int_0^{\infty}e^{ax}\ x^b \ dx$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, improper-integrals

I want to prove
$$\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty}e^{ax}\ x^b \ dx \ (a,b\in \mathbb R)$$ diverges if $a\geqq 0$.

Let $a\geqq 0.$

$$\int_0^{\infty}e^{ax}\ x^b \ dx
=\underline{\int_0^{1}e^{ax}\ x^b \ dx}_{=I_1} + \underline{\int_1^{\infty}e^{ax}\ x^b \ dx}_{=I_2}.$$

If $b\geqq 0,$ then
\begin{align}
I_2=\int_1^{\infty} e^{ax}\ x^b \ dx 
&\geqq \int_1^{\infty} e^{ax} \ dx=\infty.
\end{align}
Thus $\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty}e^{ax}\ x^b \ dx$ diverges.

I cannot prove the case of $b<0$. How should I evaluate $I_1$ or $I_2$ ?

Comment: Use the same method; since $a >= 0$ already, take the $\lim_{b \to -{\infty}}$, you find that it can only be $\infty$.

Comment: @SnipingPoodle: The number $b$ is *fixed* – or am I misunderstanding your remark?

Comment: @Martin R I meant for when $'b < 0'$, if $a >0$ already --> 

_I cannot prove the case of $b < 0$. How should I evaluate $I_1$ or $I_2$?_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a=0$ then $\int_0^\infty e^{ax} x^b \, dx$ diverges because (at least) one of the integrals
$$
 I_1 = \int_0^1 x^b \, dx \, , \quad I_2 = \int_1^\infty x^b \, dx
$$
diverges. ($I_1$ diverges if $b \le -1$, and $I_2$ diverges if $b \ge -1$.)

If $a > 0$ then choose an integer $k$ with $k+b > 0$, so that
$$
 e^{ax} x^b \ge \frac{(ax)^k}{k!} x^b = \frac{a^k}{k!} x^{k+b} \, .
$$
This implies the divergence of $\int_1^\infty e^{ax} x^b \, dx$. (This works for all values of $b$.) Roughly speaking, we are using that the exponential function “grows faster than any polynomial” for $x \to \infty$.

Comment: @Martin_R I think that I have to choose $k$ not with $k+b>0$ but with $k+b+1>0$. $\int_1^{\infty} x^{k+b} dx = [\frac{1}{k+b+1}\ \ x^{k+b+1}\ \ \ ]_1^{\infty}$ diverges when $k+b+1>0.$

Comment: @Luca: Both choices work. If $k+b > 0$ then also $k+b+1 > 0$. We need only *some* $k$ to demonstrate the divergence, it does not have to be the best possible $k$.

Comment: @Martin_R It's clear to me. Thank you.